# Finished Study, Any tips?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, programming-languages

Hi finished doing 3 IT diplomas, I have customer service experience, have just started an open source project and will be joining some others already going...

Had anybody got any other hot tips on how to get my foot in the door with a programming job?

Anything, be creative with your answer... or don't be... anything will be good from someone already programming for work...

Cheers folks, Hope you're having a good one :)

Comment: Hmm, this would be a better fit at http://programmers.stackexchange.com , as it's programmER related, not (directly) programmING related. (btw, 3 IT diplomas? *scratches head*)

Comment: 3 IT diplomas isn't anything in the programming world, not trashing your hard work. Some best programmers didn't even finish college. Maybe start working hard on the open source work. Would be a nice pointer, in your CV, to what you have done.

Comment: Yeah, I know 3 diplomas can be nothing, a lot of positions require degrees, sorry wasn't trying to blow my own trumpet because it's not a huge trumpet to blow haha , but more give my situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firstly question yourself, why do you want to get into programming? what is it about programming that motivates you?

then ask yourself if you were given a choice between a programming job and a job doing something other than programming, how much would you want to do the programming job?

once you know the answers to those questions, getting a job won't be a problem.

it is a matter of motivation. you sound somewhat motivated to me since you are doing OSS work (keep it up).

i've been programming for the last few years, but starting to get the jaded feeling, and losing the motivation, so will probably move to a different field at some point soon, then look into whether it was a sincere desire to understand programming or just doing the work to pay the bills.

remember there are always companies out there looking for *good* programmers, so it's not a matter of if but *when* you will get a job, so be a bit picky if you know you have the skillz.

also don't take yourself too seriously. make sure you have fun. if you're not having at least some fun in programming, do something else.

Comment: thanks man, it's great to hear opinions from people working in the field for some time, thanks!

Comment: no prob. do remember to vote up the answers you find helpful though.

Comment: also accept an answer by checking it, if you think it answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following:

1. Write an appealing resume/CV
2. Use internet job sites such as www.jobserve.com and www.monster.com
3. Investigate companies in your area who might be recruiting
4. Get and read a copy of "What color is your parachute!"

I think times are perhaps a bit tougher these days but I found my first programming job during the dot-com bust back in the early 2000s so if its anything like back then there are still plenty of jobs around...

Hope this helps!

nick.

Comment: Yeah, from all reports the IT market is picking up in Australia... but I have only been getting interest from IT support jobs, which is a start, but I'm think of things for the next 1-2 years to help me get a PROGRAMMING job if I can't get one now... btw, my resume, Im all over that...    points 2-3 I'm all over as well, I'll check out the book on point 4 though, thanks Nick.

Comment: No problem. Feel free to vote up my answer if it was useful :)